# too many memory references for `mov' when calling a golang function with C by using inline assembly

Tags: c, go, inline-assembly, calling-convention

I'm trying to call a golang function from my C code. Golang does not use the standard x86_64 calling convention, so I have to resort to implementing the transition myself. As gcc does not want to mix cdecl with the x86_64 convention,
I'm trying to call the function using inline assembly:

```
void go_func(struct go_String filename, void* key, int error){
    void* f_address = (void*)SAVEECDSA;
    asm volatile("  sub     rsp, 0xe0;           \t\n\
                    mov     [rsp+0xe0], rbp;   \t\n\
                    mov     [rsp], %0;            \t\n\
                    mov     [rsp+0x8], %1;       \t\n\
                    mov    [rsp+0x18], %2;       \t\n\
                    call    %3;                     \t\n\
                    mov     rbp, [rsp+0xe0];   \t\n\
                    add     rsp, 0xe0;"          
                    :
                    : "g"(filename.str), "g"(filename.len), "g"(key), "g"(f_address)
                    : );
    return;
}
```

Sadly the compiler always throws an error at me that I dont understand:

```
./code.c:241: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
```

This corresponds to this line: `mov     [rsp+0x18], %2;       \t\n\` If I delete it, the compilation works. I don't understand what my mistake is...

I'm compiling with the -masm=intel flag so I use Intel syntax. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Post your answer as an answer, not an edit to the question.  And BTW, you can use `push` if you simply change the number that you `sub` from RSP to account for it.  Your "answer" has multiple bugs that I warned about in my answer: you don't tell the compiler that the call-clobbered registers are clobbered, and you step on the red-zone because you don't `sub` enough stack space to go past it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `"g"` constraint allows the compiler to pick memory or register, so obviously you'll end up with `mov mem,mem` if that happens.  `mov` can have at most 1 memory operand.  (Like all x86 instructions, at most one explicit memory operand is possible.)

Use `"ri"` constraints for the inputs that will be moved to a memory destination, to allow register or immediate but not memory.

Also, you're modifying RSP so you can't safely use memory source operands.  The compiler is going to assume it can use addressing modes like `[rsp+16]` or `[rsp-4]`.  So you can't use `push` instead of `mov`.

---

You also need to declare clobbers on all the call-clobbered registers, because the function call will do that.  (Or better, maybe ask for the inputs in those call-clobbered registers so the compiler doesn't have to bounce them through call-preserved regs like RBX.  But you need to make those operands read/write or declare separate output operands for the same registers to let the compiler know they'll be modified.)

So probably your best bet for efficiency is something like

```
int ecx, edx, edi, esi; // dummy outputs as clobbers
register int r8 asm("r8d");  // for all the call-clobbered regs in the calling convention
register int r9 asm("r9d");
register int r10 asm("r10d");
register int r11 asm("r11d");
// These are the regs for x86-64 System V.
//  **I don't know what Go actually clobbers.**

asm("sub  rsp, 0xe0\n\t"    // adjust as necessary to align the stack before a call
    // "push args in reverse order"
    "push  %[fn_len] \n\t"
    "push  %[fn_str] \n\t"
    "call \n\t"
    "add   rsp, 0xe0 + 3*8 \n\t"  // pop red-zone skip space + pushed args

       // real output in RAX, and dummy outputs in call-clobbered regs
    : "=a"(retval), "=c"(ecx), "=d"(edx), "=D"(edi), "=S"(esi), "=r"(r8), "=r"(r9), "=r"(r10), "=r"(r11)
    : [fn_str] "ri" (filename.str), [fn_len] "ri" (filename.len), etc.  // inputs can use the same regs as dummy outputs
    :  "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3", "xmm4", "xmm5", "xmm6", "xmm7",  // All vector regs are call-clobbered
       "xmm8", "xmm9", "xmm10", "xmm11", "xmm12", "xmm13", "xmm14", "xmm15",
       "memory"  // if you're passing any pointers (even read-only), or the function accesses any globals,
                 // best to make this a compiler memory barrier
    );
```

**Notice that the output are *not* early-clobber, so the compiler *can* (at its option) use those registers for inputs, but we're not forcing it so the compiler is still free to use some other register or an immediate.**

Upon further discussion, Go functions don't clobber RBP, so there's no reason to save/restore it manually.  The only reason you might have wanted to is that locals might use RBP-relative addressing modes, and older GCC made it an error to declare a clobber on RBP when compiling without `-fomit-frame-pointer`.  (I think.  Or maybe I'm thinking of EBX in 32-bit PIC code.)

---

Also, if you're using the x86-64 System V ABI, beware that inline asm must not clobber the red-zone.  The compiler assumes that doesn't happen and there's no way to declare a clobber on the red zone or even set `-mno-redzone` on a per-function basis.  So you probably need to `sub rsp, 128 +  0xe0`.  Or `0xe0` already includes enough space to skip the red-zone if that's not part of the callee's args.

Comment: Dude, you are a lifesaver! I learn so much from your responses. Thanks again! edit: will accept once I tested it tomorrow. Not sure if my way of calling the function is the best way, but I'm trying to emulate what Golang does when calling a function.

Comment: @reijin: updated with an example of clobbers + register inputs that should allow inputs to be in call-clobbered registers, at the compiler's option.

Comment: Thanks for the update, right now my code crashes the allocation of a golang object (in a subroutine), so I guess I'm somehow killing an important register in my other code that is required for context when I call the golang function. I have to find out what exactly goes wrong here. Go clobbers rbp in that sense as it creates a new stack frame and adds its position to rbp. The runtime always has a list of all the called functions with their stack frames in rbp. Right now I'm having problems successfully going past the `call` instruction. Afterwards I'll figure out what clubbers I have to set.

Comment: @reijin: I don't know what registers Go treats as call-clobbered, but I just updated my answer with the complete set of call-clobbered x86-64 System V registers.

Comment: @reijin: Are you sure Go doesn't restore the caller's RBP before returning?  Part of making a traditional stack frame is *saving* the caller's RBP so you can restore it with `leave` or `pop rbp`.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. What I meant was temporarily add its stack frame. Golang does not actually clubber rbp, it restores it before going back to the caller.

Comment: @reijin: Then there's no reason to save/restore `rbp` inside your inline asm.  It's just like RBX or R15 as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: yeah... I was so caught up in imitating a golang function call by looking at the disassembly of a different function call as a template that I didn't think about that it's actually part of the x86-64 cc. 
Thanks!

Comment: I edited my question to include the final code I needed to call into golang. I had to use `mov` as it doesn't move `rsp`. Still: thank you for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

The original poster added this solution as an edit to their question:

If someone ever finds this, the accepted answer does not help you when you try to call golang code with inline asm! The accepted answer only helps with my initial problem, which helped me to fix the golangcall. Use something like this:**

```
void* __cdecl go_call(void* func, __int64 p1, __int64 p2, __int64 p3, __int64 p4){
    void* ret;
    asm volatile("  sub     rsp, 0x28;             \t\n\
                    mov     [rsp], %[p1];                      \t\n\
                    mov     [rsp+0x8], %[p2];                      \t\n\
                    mov     [rsp+0x10], %[p3];                      \t\n\
                    mov     [rsp+0x18], %[p4];                      \t\n\      
                    call    %[func_addr];               \t\n\
                    add     rsp, 0x28; "     
                    :
                    : [p1] "ri"(p1), [p2] "ri"(p2), 
                    [p3] "ri"(p3), [p4] "ri"(p4), [func_addr] "ri"(func)
                    : );
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This "answer" has multiple bugs that I warned about in my answer: you don't tell the compiler about the call-clobbered registers, and you step on the red-zone because you don't sub enough stack space to go past it.   `sub rsp, 0x80` / 4x push / call / `add rsp, 0x80 + 4*8` should do the trick, along with clobbers as shown in my answer.  There's no need to use `mov` to put args on the stack, push works perfectly fine.  (@michael: I know this will ping you, but I'm posting for the benefit of future readers.)

Comment: @PeterCordes :Understood. For other readers - my intent of posting this was to capture the OP's late edit, and I was taking no technical responsibility for it ;-). It was marked a community Wiki as I felt it was probably at least reasonable to move his update to an answer whether it be a good or bad answer. What I forgot to do was remove his solution from the question.Oops.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Okok, I get it. I prefer the `mov` way, as it doesn't force me to do the additional `sub` call. But I guess it's clearer to use `push`. Regarding your point on redzone and clubbered registers: I'm aware of it, it's just that I didn't run into any errors (yet), so this works fine for now. Your answer is still the better and more fleshed-out one!

Comment: @reijin: If you ignore the red-zone, it's `mov` that needs a `sub rsp, offset`.  With `push` you can just start pushing to move RSP for free.  But since you need to skip over the red-zone, both ways need one `sub` and one `add`.  The only advantage to `mov` is that you can see explicitly which offset you're storing what, instead of having to push in reverse order of args.  (right-most arg first, so it's at the highest address).

Comment: @reijin: it's common to write inline asm that happens to work in one test, but is actually broken and will cause hard-to-debug problems down the road after changes to some *unrelated* code.  Or just with a new compiler version and/or build options (especially link-time optimization enabling inlining across source files.)